# Array from matrix fields without quotations

Tags: plugin-elementapi, elementquery, element

I am trying to create an array `bodyBlocks` by looping through all of my matrix fields called `blockTextContent`:

```
$bodyBlocks = [];
foreach ($entry->getFieldValue('pageBuilder')->all() as $block){
    switch ($block->type->handle) {
        case 'blockText':               
            $bodyBlocks[] = $block->blockTextContent;
            break;
        }
    }

// Begin defining the response data for this entry
$data = [
    'title' => $entry->title,
    'slug' => $entry->url,
    'status' => $entry->status,
    'textArea' => $bodyBlocks
];
```

The JSON response is as below, focusing on the `textArea` line.

```
"title": "Title Here",
"slug": "slug-here",
"status": "live",
"textArea": [
    "<p>Text from first 1st block</p>",
    "<p>Text from first 2nd block</p>",
    "<p>Text from first 3rd block</p>",
],
"heroBanner": "img.jpg",
```

The above is working as expected, cool. BUT I'd like the response to appear as below. Merging that matrix field in to one line in `textArea`, so without the separating quotation marks and surrounding square brackets [ ]?

My desired response would look like this in the end:

```
"title": "Title Here",
"slug": "slug-here",
"status": "live",
"textArea": "<p>Text from first 1st block</p> <p>Text from first 2nd block</p> <p>Text from first 3rd block</p>",
"heroBanner": "img.jpg",
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to join the array into a string, like so:

```
// Begin defining the response data for this entry
$data = [
    'title' => $entry->title,
    'slug' => $entry->url,
    'status' => $entry->status,
    'textArea' => implode(' ',$bodyBlocks)
];
```